# SQL/Wordpress/AJAX : Format JSON With Loop

Tags: php, mysql, json, ajax, wordpress

**PROBLEM**

I'm trying to query my database (wp_usermeta table) and export it in a JSON format to be processed by an autocomplete plugin. I need the data to be formatted as such:

```
{"suggestion":"copmany1", "umeta_id":"1"},{"suggestion":"company2", "umeta_id":"2"}, etc.
```

**SO FAR**

My current code outputs the info as such:

```
{"suggestions":["concept9 test","Company"],"data":["58","77"]}
```

This is my code:

```
$query = $_GET["query"];



    // escape values passed to db to avoid sql-injection
    $query = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT DISTINCT umeta_id, meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key='company' AND meta_value LIKE '".$query."%' order by umeta_id" );

    $suggestions = array();

    foreach($query as $row) {
        $suggestions[] = $row->meta_value;
        $data[] = $row->umeta_id;

        $response1 = array(
        'suggestions' => $suggestions,
        'data' => $data,
    );
    }


    $response = json_encode( $response1 );
    echo $response;
    exit();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
$query = $_GET["query"];
// escape values passed to db to avoid sql-injection
$query = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT DISTINCT umeta_id, meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key='company' AND meta_value LIKE '".$query."%' order by umeta_id" );
$suggestions = array();
foreach($query as $row) {
    array_push($suggestions, array(
            'suggestion' => $row->meta_value,
            'umeta_id' => $row->umeta_id
        )
    );
}
echo json_encode( $suggestions );
exit();
```

Comment here if you need further explanation

Comment: Hi @Sasha89 - thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately, this yields null. This is maybe because the foreach loop will go through the queries, not the companies. Perhaps we need another loop inside it since the wp_usermeta table is formatted like this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_usermeta ? thanks!

Comment: can you add this line inside foreach and post results: var_dump($row); die;

Comment: this is what i get `object(stdClass)#451 (2) { ["umeta_id"]=> string(2) "58" ["meta_value"]=> string(13) "concept9 test" }`

Comment: That is what i expected, so im not sure why you get "null"

Comment: remove the vardump/die from the foreach loop, and add this right before the "echo json_encode..." line: var_dump($suggestions);die;

Comment: maybe you are still echoing $response1, and not $suggestions. Double check everything.

Comment: very strange - i tried removing the vardump, and i do indeed get null. When i added the vardump before the json_encode i get the same: `bject(stdClass)#490 (2) { ["umeta_id"]=> string(2) "77" ["meta_value"]=> string(7) "Company" } null`

Comment: oh god, you are completely right..Was outputting the old array. it should work now! i get `[{"suggestion":"concept9 test","umeta_id":"58"},{"suggestion":"Company","umeta_id":"77"}]` - thanks so much!